# removing all character from string except a-z in array

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to read words from the text file and store it in array.Problem from the code i tried as shown below is that it reads all characters such as    "words," and "read." but i only want "words" and "read" in an array.

```
public String[] openFile() throws IOException
{
    int noOfWords=0;
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File(path));
    while(sc2.hasNext()) 
    {
         noOfWords++;
         sc2.next();
    }

    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(new File(path));
    String bagOfWords[] = new String[noOfWords];
    for(int i = 0;i<noOfWords;i++)
    {
         bagOfWords[i] =sc3.next();
    }

    sc3.close();
    sc2.close();
    return bagOfWords;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex replace :

```
replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z]+)","");
```

And apply that line to

```
bagOfWords[i] = sc3.next().replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z]+)","");
```

Comment: The parentheses and + are not necessary you just need [^a-zA-Z].  It would probably benefit the OP if you explained the regex pattern and how the replaceAll uses it.

Comment: yes i know, i think + will replace a group of chars rather than every char. So it not waste memory address for every regex match

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfWords; i++) {
     bagOfWords[i] = sc3.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want only letters. In this case, you can use `Character.isLetter(char)` method.

Snippet:

```
String token = "word1";
String newToken = "";
for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {
    char c = token.charAt(i);
    if(java.lang.Character.isLetter(c)){
        newToken += c;
    }
}
System.out.println(newToken);
```